# while dynamic loading js, why keep script type="text/javascript"

Tags: javascript

```
var ga = document.createElement('script');
ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ?
      'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +
      '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

While in the above code(in Google Analytics) ,
I wonder why they keep writing `ga.type = 'text/javascript'` ,
I've tried not adding it and it seems working well in modern browser
I thought I should have missed something

Comment: I think it's just for compatibility with old browsers. HTML5 browsers don't need it.

Comment: @elclanrs—it was only ever needed for validation and the rare case of also using some other scripting language in the same document (IE used to allow [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260861%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), dunno if it still does). The vast majority of browsers have only ever supported javascript.

Comment: @elclanrs: Only if you mean *really old* browsers. The HTML5 spec is mostly things that were already widely supported as the *de-facto* standard among browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be required to pass the XHTML validator (the `type` attribute). However, every modern browser parsed `script` blocks as JavaScript anyway.

However, the HTML5 specification says you can leave it off, and it will default to `text/javascript`.